# ToggleSwitch in UWP C#

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a little question. I'm trying to create an UWP C# application, and I'm using toggle switches in the project. If I toggle the status of the ToggleSwitch from the software very often, the memory usage increases very much. Why is this happening?

The ToggleSwitch represents a boolean using binding.

I have created example code:

XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ToggleSwitch Header="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="213,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsOn="{Binding Path=TestBool, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <CheckBox Content="Two-state CheckBox" Margin="108,162,0,806" IsChecked="{Binding Path=TestBool, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Button Content="Start!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="69,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool testBool = false;

        public bool TestBool { get { return testBool; } set { if (testBool != value) { testBool = value; OnPropertyChanged(); } } }

        public MainPage()
        {
            DataContext = this;
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                TestBool = !TestBool;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Do I do something that is not possible, what do I understand wrong?

When I replace the ToggleSwitch with a CheckBox, the memory usage increases much less.

[image: Memory Usage]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a memory leak is occurring on your application, explaining why the GC failed to free it up.

Some considerations:

- Why are you implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the page level? You should implement it on a separate class. That class should hold the model and implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface itself. 
  That class is commonly denominated as a `ViewModel`, and as the name suggests holds the model for a View and it knows how to communicate any changes onto it.

  - Generally most of the problems with memory leaks with Bindings, that have been reported happen generally when utilizing compiled bindings, {x:Bind ...}, but you are utilizing the traditional bindings. You've correctly performed binding onto a dependency property, such as `IsOn` and also implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the source object, so I don't think that exists something inherently wrong with how you are spinning up the binding process.
  - You are performing 100 bindings update in a row, so even if the CPU usage should be a bit lower, it is expected that while you are iterating over the loop you will have your CPU usage increased. 
    Ps: Since you have not marked your method as `async, you will be blocking the UI thread until your loop operation ends, which might be something that you could want to change. 
    A binding update, is certainly a process with a couple of actions in the middle for each that's why I'm "confident" that the CPU usage might not be a big issue.

I don't actually have a guess, but I would strongly suggest to refactor your code to have the `ViewModel` class implemented as an extra class, and observe if the memory leaks observed seize to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your invoke is draining CPU.

[image]

My answer is you should think again about your app's architecture.